# Empty field value showing in webform email content

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a file attach field in my webform. When i have submit my webform without this field,in my email content showing like "ATTACHED FILE: [webform_submission:values:attach_file]".
I have checked "Exclude empty elements" in my email handler.This is working for all other fields in my form except this "File attach" field.How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Similar question was recently answered by the Webform module developer at drupal.org:

"You might just need to append the :clear prefix.

[webform_submission:values:element_value] => [webform_submission:values:element_value:clear]"

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2982562

So, in your case use replacement pattern: [webform_submission:values:attach_file:clear]

Comment: Thank you..its working.But now the link (if i have attached file) is missing and link  to file is  showing as plain text.Can i solve this?